# jquery click event to trigger function with parameters

Tags: jquery

I am using a small javascript function which i want to bind to the `click` event of a `span (spancat)` element. But when the function is defined with argument , it is not fired. Works fine for `chk_1` as well as the commented line. Below is the code

```
$(document).ready(function()
   $("[name=chk_1]").on('click',showdata(this));
   $("[name=spancat]").on('click',showhidechild('param1'));
   //$("[name=spancat]").on('click',showhidechild));
});

function showhidechild(childele){
            alert('test');
}
```

**I saw the thread mentioned in duplicate and using a working example as well. But could not figure out why it doesnt work in the second place it is used. it is used in the same manner in both cases.**

Comment: You should note that `name` is not a valid attribute for a `span` element

Comment: oh i didnt know that. But that doesnt seem to be the issue. Because even span click event worked for another span(with name)

Comment: No the issue is because you've not attached the event handlers correctly. See the question I marked as duplicate for the solution